# Satirical prophecy

Tags: word-choice

I have been trying to write stories about  possible but improbable futures sort of like Idiocracy or Conan O'Brian's "in the year two thousand" skit.

*Will* sounds too much like *must*, and *could* makes the story sound dependent on  present action.  I want a story that describes  *A* future not *THE* future.

Either way I go I overuse *could, may, will* or *must*.

What wording would fit such improbable prophecies - unlikely future claims?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is too vague as written. If you'd like us to help you with an existing piece, please read our critique guidelines. http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work

Comment: I think I understand the question: how to word highly uncertain claims about future, e.g. "in fifty years everyone *might* be using flying cars".

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [How to write a prophecy?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/how-to-write-a-prophecy) mardi, is your question addressed by this? If not, let's edit this to make the differences clear.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - I agree this is vague (even with the edit, although that certainly helps). It's also close to asking what to write.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if it's to be *satirical*, I'd forfeit all "may, might, could" etc.

I'd go with *Simple Present*, then augment every single claim with "or not."

> *In the year 3000 all religions are recognized as highly infective memetic diseases. Or not.
>  All "infected/believers" are quarantined in closed "holy cities". Or not.*

Comment: Or you can avoid the "or not" by doing something totally contradicting in satirical way: In year 3000 every country is perfect democracy, where people can choose from one total dictator, who is currently Kim Jong The Fifteenth